# Regex not working when I use currency sign

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression to extract values like **$parameter$** from a string. It's working for strings like:

> Hello Mr. $name$. Today is $dateOfWeek$ and we should wear some $clothes$.

This is my regex:

```
\$((?:\w*\s*)+)\(?(\d*)\)?\$
```

But it's not working to extract parameters if there is a currency sign in the string:

> Hello Mr. Your balance is $$moneyValue.

If I run my regex on the string above, the parameter **$moneyValue$** is not being extracted. The value extracted is **$$**.

How can I change my regex to extract parameters like **$$parameter$**? A parameter can include white space and more than 1 word.

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: Do you want to extract `$$value` or `$$value$`?

Comment: I would like to extract $value$. I need to ignore the first $ from $$paramter$ because the first one is just to put the sign before value - ex.: $10.00 ... i get the $value$ to replace for 10.00

Comment: `$${paramter}` has curly braces and your reges doesn't have any. Are you sure your question is framed right?

Comment: You should not use `$` to indicate where the parameter is. It's confusing things with the `$` that is actually supposed to be in your string. Try giving us a more "real" example of input and output.

Comment: @anubhava don't have curly braces. i've edited the comment

Comment: What if your input has something like `Hello your service tax is $10.00 and balance is $$moneyValue$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex needs to be "more greedy", also I think you want a bit different type of capture group

You can try this `\$([\w\s]+)\$?`

I tested using Javascript and it works for both your cases

---

With your new restriction of the first character cannot be a white-space character:

`\$(\w+[\w\s]*)\$?`

Comment: @placplacboom that won't match, \w captures \d so you shouldn't need it, if you need other characters put them inside the []

Comment: hey Buddy..almost worked but when i put on space after dollar sign like $ $money$, it stop to work. I just need to extract $money$

Comment: The first position after the $ can not be a whitespace character

Comment: woot...almost there :) ... if the string could contains **$money(2)$**, can i use \d? This is working for me **\$(\w+[\w\s]*)\(?(\d*)\)?\$?**

Comment: @placplacboom I think you have the gist of what you need to do, maybe try using a regex testing tool for your cases regexpal.com should get you started

Answer (score 0):

```
\$([^$]+)(?=\$|\b)\$*
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/19

Comment: hey Buddy..almost worked but when i put on space after dollar sign like ***$ $money$***, it stop to work. I just need to extract **$money$**

Comment: The first position after the $ can not be a whitespace character